# Vite: Is there a possibility to exclude code elements from being built?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vite

I'm looking for a "feature" in Vite which will allow me to exclude some code from being built. As far as I remember in webpack there was a feature when you could create some comments like:

```js
###SOMETHING
<code goes here>
###END_SOMETHING
```

and this code between ###SOMETHING and ###END_SOMETHING wasn't included in output files during build process. Is there relative feature available in Vite or maybe there is another way to perform such a action? Basically code between these "tags" needs to be in file and working during `vite dev`, but it needs to be omitted by `vite build`.

I've found rollup settings but it only includes whole files.

Comment: are you thinking about `/*` and `*/`?

Comment: No no, I don't want code to be commented, I want it to be working, but just omitted while built.

Comment: what does it mean? If you don't include code in the build it won't work.

Comment: As I said in the post, code needs to be there in source file and needs to be working during `vite dev`, it just needs to be omitted while using `vite build`. I've updated the post so it's now more clear what do I mean. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible to conditionally evaluate Javascript according to the execution mode (production or development) by using the `import.meta.env` variable.

`vite dev` will run in development mode by default and `vite build` will use production mode (you can override though through `--mode`)

See https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#modes

In your case you can use `import.meta.env.DEV` to see if you are in development mode and run conditionally some code, e.g.:

```
if (import.meta.env.DEV) {
    // code runs in vite dev
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it should do the job. :)